# Cannot chain the searching in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to searching the title/body with simple search from Rails. But when I tried to put the matched string in title/body, it cannot display the expect result. Could you please help me have a check? Thank you in advance

*article.rb*

```
def self.search(query)
    # where(:title, query) -> This would return an exact match of the query
    where("title LIKE ? or body LIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
  end
```

*controller*

```
if params[:search]
      @articles = Article.search(params[:search])
    #@articles = Article.where(["title || body like ?","%#{params[:search]}%"])
    else
      @articles = Article.all
    end
```

*show*

```
<%= form_tag(articles_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Title or body" %>
 <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="submit">Search</button>
```

Please get details at github link : https://github.com/khoinguyen91/CoderSchool_blog

Comment: Missing `#` in the first parameter value i.e. `"%{query}%"` instead of `"%#{query}%"` ?

Comment: Ahh,Sorry,it's typo mistake. I corrected it in my question.

Comment: Right.. you'll need to add a bit more detail to the question then.. when you mentioned it doesn't display the expected results.. what happens instead?

Comment: It only display the page with all content I created before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, took a quick look at the rest of your code on GitHub and the problem is [here](https://github.com/khoinguyen91/CoderSchool_blog/blob/c8eac1e41b462a9ceded42de6c09b4088f97f7e8/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb#L19):

```
def index
  #@articles = Article.all
  if params[:search]
    @articles = Article.search(params[:search])
    #@articles = Article.where(["title || body like ?","%#{params[:search]}%"])
  else
    @articles = Article.all
  end
  @markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)
  if params[:tag]
    @articles = Article.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @articles = Article.all
  end
end
```

After checking for `params[:search]` you're checking for `params[:tag]` which will be blank when submitting from your search form. This means that `@articles` just gets replaced with the full list of articles (`@articles = Article.all`).

Comment: Thanks mikej, It seem my stuck point here. It worked now. I want to upvote for you but it's not enough reputation :D